# Online price Amazon API

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, amazon-web-services, amazon-product-api

I am using the Amazon API and I am using **vacuum** gem. I am trying to search products with ASIN product type to get attributes like **Price, inStock and all item attributes**, But I just receive *Manufacturer,ProductGroup,Title* attributes,

**How can I set up my search attributes?**

My code:

```
req = Vacuum.new
req.configure(
    aws_access_key_id:     '...',
    aws_secret_access_key: '...',
    associate_tag:         'tag'
)
req.associate_tag = 'foobar'
@res = req.item_lookup(query: { 'IdType' => 'ASIN', 'ItemId' => '...'})
```

My response:

```
{"ItemAttributes"=>{"Manufacturer"=>"...", "ProductGroup"=>"...", "Title"=>"..."}}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need to ensure you are requesting using the "large" ResponseGroup from the Amazon Product API, this will return almost every property associated to that ASIN.

Using your example it will look like this:

item_lookup(query: { 'IdType' => 'ASIN', 'ItemId' => '...', 'ItemSearch.Shared.ResponseGroup' => 'Large'})

Comment: Thank you, How I can know if an item is **Prime?** and how much pieces left from item?

Comment: Thank you! Here is the documentation for ResponseGroups: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSECommerceService/latest/DG/CHAP_ResponseGroupsList.html I changed the param to just 'ResponseGroup' => 'Large' and it worked.

Comment: `Medium`, `Offers`, and `OfferSummary` also return prices.